# Django Admin - Leaflet: Programmatically add a marker to existing map

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin, leaflet, geodjango

models.py:

```
class Point(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField()
```

admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Point, LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

Everything shows great.

However, I would like to manually add a pointer to the admin map if a button is pressed.

templates/admin/myapp/point/change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}
<input type="button" id="startWatchButton" value="Show marker" />
{% endblock %}
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#startWatchButton").click(function() {
        var mymap = <How to select the initialized django map?>
        var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);
    });
});
```

How can I select the already existing and initialized django admin map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps for a successfull result:

1. Get some sleep
2. [Read the Docs](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet)
3. Implement

> You can use the Leaflet API as usual. There are two ways to grab a
>   reference on the just initialized map and options.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     window.addEventListener("map:init", function (e) {
>         var detail = e.detail;
>         ...
>         L.marker([50.5, 30.5]).addTo(detail.map);
>         ...
>     }, false);
> </script>
> ```